# Divide the bigdecimal value in a list of object using java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Invoice objects with properties frequency and amount(BigDecimal).

1)Need to multiply and change the amount based on frequency with out loosing precision.Tried in the below shown code but the output is loosing some precision. amount values should be 100.

2) Is it possible to replace the amount value in the list of invoices with java 8 stream API.
 Tried using

```
invoiceList.forEach(s -> s.getAmount().multiply(new BigDecimal("10")));
```

but this wont replace the amount value in the object.
couldn't figure out using replaceAll in this case, tried below code but giving compile error,

```
 newList.replaceAll((v) -> v.getAmount().multiply(frequencyFactor.get(v.getFrequency())));
```

The whole main class is below. Cannot change any datatypes or design. I have to process the acquired list from web service.

```
public class InvoiceMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Invoice> invoiceList = Arrays.asList(new Invoice("Quarterly", new BigDecimal(300)), new Invoice("Annually", new BigDecimal(1200)));
        Map<String, BigDecimal> frequencyFactor = new HashMap<>();
        frequencyFactor.put("Annually", new BigDecimal(1.0 / 12));
        frequencyFactor.put("Quarterly", new BigDecimal(1.0 / 3));
        for (Invoice invoice : invoiceList) {
            invoice.setAmount(invoice.getAmount().multiply(frequencyFactor.get(invoice.getFrequency())));
        }
        System.out.println(invoiceList);
    }
}

class Invoice {
    private String frequency;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Invoice(String frequency, BigDecimal amount) {
        super();
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(String frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Invoice [frequency=" + frequency + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
    }
}
```

OUTPUT is:

```
[Invoice [frequency=Quarterly, amount=99.999..], Invoice [frequency=Annually, amount=99.999...]]
```

Required output is

```
[Invoice [frequency=Quarterly, amount=100], Invoice [frequency=Annually, amount=100]]
```

Comment: Considering your code I do not see why you would even require a switch since both cases have equal code.

Comment: if the frequency is "quarterly" i will divide by 3, if it is Anually, i will divide by 12, frequency factor changes by Case value.

Comment: @SampathKumarMadala But your code is _exactly_ the same in each `case`. You can replace the whole `switch` with `invoice.setAmount(invoice.getAmount().multiply(frequencyFactor.get(invoice.getFrequency())));`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog right, removed the switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flaw is using the BigDecimal constructor with a double. Then BigDecimal cannot determine a precision and uses one suitable for the double, also introducing an inprecise value (from the double).

```
new BigDecimal(1.0/12)
```

Would optimally be changed to dividing afterwards by 12: using `divideBy`.

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> divisors = ...
divisors.put("Anually", BigDecimal.valueOf(12));
...
final Map<String, BigDecimal> finalDivisors = divisors;

BigDecimal sum = invoiceList.stream()
    .map(inv -> inv.amount.divideBy(finalDivisors.get(inv.frequency))
    .sum();
```

---

***In actual code:***

```
static class Invoice {
    final BigDecimal amount;
    final int months;

    Invoice(BigDecimal amount, int months) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.months = months;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Invoice> invoices = Arrays.asList(
            new Invoice(new BigDecimal("12.50"), 3),
            new Invoice(new BigDecimal("120.50"), 12),
            new Invoice(new BigDecimal("7.25"), 3));
    BigDecimal sum = invoices.stream()
            .map(inv -> inv.amount.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(inv.months),
                                          RoundingMode.HALF_UP))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum); // 16.63
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Iam trying to get the invoice objects which will have the Bigdecimal values divided as per months. For ex:     [Invoice [frequency=Quarterly, amount=100], Invoice [frequency=Annually, amount=100]]

Comment: Doesn't `BigDecimal` throw an `ArithmeticException` if a division has a non-terminating result, and you don't specify how you want it rounded?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem for that one needs a RoundingMode; in this case it will use a precision of 2.

Comment: @SampathKumarMadala I now see. I guess you'll now have made a solution on your own / the other answer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem in what respect? Addition here uses precision 2.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution using enums.

```
    public enum Frequency {
        ANUALLY(12), QUARTERLY(3);

        private final int divideBy;

        Frequency(final int div) { this.divideBy = div; }

        public int getDivideBy() { return this.divideBy; }
    }

    public class InvoiceMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Invoice> invoiceList = Arrays.asList(new Invoice(Frequency.QUARTERLY,new     BigDecimal(300)), new Invoice(Frequency.ANUALLY, new BigDecimal(1200)));
        for(Invoice invoice: invoiceList) {
            invoice.setAmount(invoice.getAmount().divide(invoice.getFrequency().getDivideBy())));
        }
        System.out.println(invoiceList);
    }
}


class Invoice {
private Frequency frequency;
private BigDecimal amount;
public Invoice(Frequency frequency, BigDecimal amount) {
    super();
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.amount = amount;
}
public Frequency getFrequency() {
    return frequency;
}
public void setFrequency(Frequency frequency) {
    this.frequency = frequency;
}
public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Invoice [frequency=" + frequency + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: Yes an enum for the categories of invoices is much better. 4 should still be 3 I think.

Comment: @JoopEggen fixed. In the original question it stated "multiply with 4" so I copied this ;)

Comment: why I am not able to invoke divideBy method available on BigDecimal ?? Iam using java 1.8v

Comment: @SampathKumarMadala because the method is apparently named `BigDecimal#divide` instead of `#divideBy`. I modified my answer.

Comment: @thepieterdc BigDecimal#divide method takes BigDecimal as parameter. But in the code there is compile error due to parameter int.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not sure if you already solved your problem but if you take Double instead of BigDezimal you'll get the correct output I tryed it like this:

```
public class InvoiceMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Invoice> invoiceList = Arrays.asList(new 
    Invoice("Quarterly",300.0),new Invoice("Annually", 1200.0));            
    Map<String, Double> frequencyFactor = new HashMap<>();
    frequencyFactor.put("Annually", (Double)(1.0 / 12));
    frequencyFactor.put("Quarterly",(Double)(1.0 / 3));
    for (Invoice invoice : invoiceList) {
        switch (invoice.getFrequency()) {
        case "Quarterly": // divide by 4, to convert to Monthly
        invoice.setAmount(invoice.getAmount() *
(frequencyFactor.get(invoice.getFrequency())));    
            break;
        case "Annually": // divide by 12, to convert to Monthly
            invoice.setAmount(invoice.getAmount() * 
(frequencyFactor.get(invoice.getFrequency())));
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(invoiceList);
 }
}

class Invoice {
private String frequency;
private Double amount;

public Invoice(String frequency, Double amount) {
    super();
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getFrequency() {
    return frequency;
}

public void setFrequency(String frequency) {
    this.frequency = frequency;
}

public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(Double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Invoice [frequency=" + frequency + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
}
}
```

And here's the output:
[Invoice [frequency=Quarterly, amount=100.0], Invoice [frequency=Annually, amount=100.0]]

Cheers,
kEbO

Comment: I can't change the datatype of amount.

Answer (score 1):

After reading other answers,I found what you really want is calculates the **monthly** `Invoice`, you can introduce a [Value Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object) `Invoice` & an enum `Frequency` here to make the code according to OO way and simpler:

```
enum Frequency {
    ANUALLY(12), QUARTERLY(3), MONTHLY(1);

    private final int months;

    Frequency(final int months) {
        this.months = months;
    }

    private BigDecimal monthly(BigDecimal amount) {
        return amount.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(months));
    }
}

class Invoice {
    private Frequency frequency;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Invoice(Frequency frequency, BigDecimal amount) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    private Invoice monthly() {
        return new Invoice(Frequency.MONTHLY, frequency.monthly(this.amount));
    }

    // getters are ignored here
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Invoice [frequency=" + frequency + ", amount=" + amount + "]";
    }
}
```

**THEN** your main class can using stream api as below:

```
class InvoiceMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Invoice> invoiceList = Arrays.asList(
                new Invoice(Frequency.QUARTERLY, new BigDecimal(300)),
                new Invoice(Frequency.ANUALLY, new BigDecimal(1200))
        );

        System.out.println(invoiceList.stream().map(Invoice::monthly)
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

### Output

```
[
  Invoice [frequency=MONTHLY, amount=100],
  Invoice [frequency=MONTHLY, amount=100]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I can't change the datatypes or design. I will get Invoices list from webservice, and I have to proceed from there.

Comment: @SampathKumarMadala Not at all. It is my pleasure. But I can tell you that you can control the design by yourself if the client code is wrote by you even if the data from webservice.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the responses, I have modified the frequency factor values, and replace multiply to divide.

```
Map<String,BigDecimal> frequencyFactor = new HashMap<>();
    frequencyFactor.put("Monthly", BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
    frequencyFactor.put("Annually",BigDecimal.valueOf(12));
    frequencyFactor.put("Yearly", BigDecimal.valueOf(12));
    frequencyFactor.put("Quaterly", BigDecimal.valueOf(3));
    frequencyFactor.put("Semiannually", BigDecimal.valueOf(6));

    for (Subscription invoice : newList) {
        invoice.setAmount(invoice.getAmount().divide(frequencyFactor.get(invoice.getFrequency()),2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
}
    newList.forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));
```